# R - removing rows where values of one column fail to match another column

Tags: r

I have a line of code in my R script which calculates a percentage from my dataset `edata` regarding how often the values of two columns `GazeCueTarget.CRESP` and `GazeCueTarget.RESP` match up per row of data.

I want to be able to delete all the rows where the values from both of these columns do not match up. So if my below code tells me 97% of the time the values of `GazeCueTarget.CRESP` match that of `GazeCueTarget.RESP` on a given row of my data, I want to be able to get rid of the remaining 3% where the values mismatch.

This is what I have produced to give me a percentage for when the rows match up.
Any advice would be very much appreciated. I think the solution should be quite simple but I am not sure.

```
paste0((100*with(edata, mean(GazeCueTarget.CRESP==GazeCueTarget.RESP, na.rm = "TRUE"))), "%")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try subsetting off non matching rows:

```
edata <- edata[edata$GazeCueTarget.CRESP == edata$GazeCueTarget.RESP, ]
```

Comment: That is on the right lines, thank you. But I am looking to remove any code that doesn't match, rather than forcing the values to be the same.